# jsonrpc eth_accounts returns no accounts

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts, json-rpc

I have a running geth node and by using `geth account new` command I created a new account:

```
$ geth account list
```

> Account #0: {47978a69f410d0f...} ...

Nevertheless, when using json rpc call to list my ether accounts a null result is obtained:

```
$ curl -X POST --data
```

> '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_accounts","params":[],"id":1}'
>   http://127.0.0.1:8545
>
> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":[]}

Why is that? Any hint? Thanks in advance!

I launched geth with the following command:

```
$geth --rpc --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" --rpcport "8545" --testnet 
--etherbase "0x47978a6...."
```

Is it possible that geth working on testnet gets confused on json rpc calls? Do I need to specify somehow in these calls to use testnet and not mainnet?

Comment: Try `id:0` or remove `id` param.

Comment: Same result and error...:

`$ curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_accounts","params":[],"id":0}' http://127.0.0.1:8545
 {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":0,"result":[]}
`
`$ curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_accounts","params":[]}' http://127.0.0.1:8545
 {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32700,"message":"missing request id"}}´`

Comment: What is id by the way? The id of what?

Comment: `eth.accounts[]` is the index of the wallets that you are querying, in your case `0`, the coinbase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely the problem is related to node running on testnet and account being valid only on mainnet.

I created a new account on testnet and json-rpc query worked perfectly:

> $geth --testnet account list
>
> $geth --testnet account new Address: {3b877e80b5c0...}
>
> $geth --testnet account list  Account #0: {3b877e80b5c0...
>
> $ curl -X POST -d '{"method":"eth_accounts","id":0}' 127.0.0.1:8545
>     {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":0,"result":["0x3b877e80...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In the original post the creation of the account does not have a --testnet command line option, so maybe that's the case. Did the OP trying to find the account on the mainnet?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use the `params` field in your call. By doing this, you are executing this command: `eth.accounts[]` which returns a null value. If you want to get a list of all the accounts, you should be executing `eth.accounts`. So, your RPC command should be:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"method":"eth_accounts","id":1}' 127.0.0.1:8545
```

P.S: I'm assuming you already enabled RPC on port 8545. Through the console, you can use `admin.startRPC()` to start RPC.

Comment: Thanks for the simplification, but unfortunatelly, same result: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":[]}

Comment: Did you check with other commands?

Comment: Yes, it responds correctly to other commands: $ curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"web3_sha3","params":["0x68656c6c6f20776f726c64"],"id":64}' localhost:8545
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":64,"result":"0x47173285a8d7341e5e972fc677286384f802f8ef42a5ec5f03bbfa254cb01fad"}

Comment: Maybe problem is related to geth using testnet and json rpc using mainnet... is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Enable the **web3** RPC API when starting **geth**:

```
geth --rpc --rpcapi "web3" --rpcport "8545"
```

or if you want all APIs run:

```
geth --rpc --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" --rpcport "8545"
```

Comment: I just did it, but exactly the same result, geth account list shows the account but jsonrpc doesn't :-(

Comment: Problem is not API not responding, but responding null result. In fact, it responds correctly to other commands such as: $ curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"web3_sha3","params":["0x68656c6c6f20776f726c64"],"id":64}' localhost:8545
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":64,"result":"0x47173285a8d7341e5e972fc677286384f802f8ef42a5ec5f03bbfa254cb01fad"}

Comment: It's likely that you are not sending the correct JSON object. Use web3 and call the same function: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethaccounts   as the curl parameters are correct (as suggested in the documentation).