# Unable to get the Ethereum accounts (eth_accounts) using the JSON RPC

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, json-rpc

I launched an Ethereum installation with the [Amazon Blockchain Templates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/blockchain-templates/latest/developerguide/blockchain-templates-create-stack.html) using the simplest installation, the **docker-local** with a private network (not connected to the public Ethereum network).

Everything seems to work correctly. I can see the Ethereum Network Status website and the Ethereum Block Explorer website.

The JSON RPC (`:8545`) seems to work OK too:

```
# This works:
curl -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"net_listening","params":[],"id":67}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8545
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":67,"result":true}

# This works too:
bash-4.2# curl -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getBalance","params":["0x0ADfCCa4B2a1132F82488546AcA086D7E24EA324", "latest"],"id":1}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8545
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0xcc19df002cd1b40000"}
```

But when I try to list all the accounts, I get an empty array, when there should be a list of 3 accounts:

```
bash-4.2# curl -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_accounts","params":[],"id":1}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8545
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":[]}
```

Does anyone know what can be happening? I tried [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8142/jsonrpc-eth-accounts-returns-no-accounts) solution with no luck, as the daemon is running and I'm not able to change the `geth` status, and it seems (I'm not sure) I'm not a launching it on a testnet (no `--testnet` parameter)

The `geth` running inside the container seems to be well configured to serve all the JSON RPC calls:

```
/opt/ethereum-go/bin/geth --nodiscover --networkid 1234 --rpc --rpcapi web3,net,eth --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcvhosts * --rpccorsdomain * --ws --wsapi web3,net,eth --wsaddr 0.0.0.0 --wsport 8546 --wsorigins bin --mine --minerthreads 1 --etherbase 0x0ADfCCa4B2a1132F82488546AcA086D7E24EA324 --targetgaslimit 8000000 --gasprice 0
```

Can someone give me a hand, please?

Comment: `there should be a list of 3 accounts` - where exactly do you configure the GETH node to unlock 3 accounts? I do not see it in the GETH configuration at the bottom of your question.

Comment: You need to activate more of the APIs to access these: personal is the one you are looking for.